# UPDATE statement with WHERE calsue from 2 tables

Tags: sql, set, sql-update, where-clause

looking for some advice on how to perform an update to a table, but where my 2 WHERE statements come from different tables.  Here's what I'm thinking:

```
UPDATE table1
SET table1.t1field=('new parameter');
FROM table1
WHERE table1.t1field > ('parameter') 
INNER JOIN
table 2
ON table2.t2field  = ('my other parameter');
```

Basically, what I want to do is update X, where X = myparameter (from table 1) and myparameter2 (from table 2).

Am I getting the syntax right?  If I take out the semi-colon after the new parameter, I get a "SQL command not properly ended" error, but with it left in, I think it's trying to update everything in the table!  Obviously I don't want this, I only want it tp update that paramater if it meets the 2 criteria.

Thanks for any help you can give.

Comment: on what fields, you are joining both tables??

Comment: Which RDBMS are you using?

Answer (score 0):

It should be something like following:

```
UPDATE table1
INNER JOIN table2
ON table2.join_field = table1.join_field
SET table1.t1field=('new parameter'), table2.t2field  = ('my other parameter')
FROM table1
WHERE table1.t1field > ('parameter');
```

Answer (score 0):

The correct syntax for update queries with join is the following:

```
UPDATE t1
SET t1.[column]=[value]
FROM table1 t1 INNER JOIN table2  t2 ON [join condition]
WHERE [conditions]
```